# Why won't certain C string library functions (i.e. strtok) accept a char * that hasn't been allocated with malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, strtok, string.h

Recently I was working on a school project which involved writing an assembler in C, and I encountered a problem with passing a pointer to `strtok`.  I got past the error in my code, but I want to understand why what I was doing didn't work.

Below is a simplified example of a function where the error was occurring.

```
void processText(FILE *f) { //takes a file opened for reading.
  char *token, *temp;
  int len;
  char buff[81]; //line buffer

  while (fgets(buff, 81, f) != NULL) { //read in each line one at a time
    len = strlen(buff);
    token = strtok(buff, "#"); //first assignment

    /*if there is a comment, strip and print it*/
    if (len != strlen(token)) {
      printf("comment: %s", strtok(NULL, "#"));
    }

    //len = strlen(token);
    //temp = malloc(len + 1);
    //strcpy(temp, token);
    //token = strtok(temp, " ");

    token = strtok(token, " "); //this segfaults...

    printf("first word: %s\n", token);
    //free(temp);
  }
}
```

Replacing the offending line with the commented code block above it (and freeing temp at the end) fixes the problem, but it requires me to make an extra copy of my data for apparently no reason, and it leaves me wondering why I can't use the existing data unless I refer to it a certain way.

As I understand it, the `strtok` function accepts parameters `char *` and `const char *` respectively.  It seems to me, that after the first assignment `token` and `buff` should appear to `strtok` as `char *`'s pointing to the same location--that is, that the value `strtok` receives as its first parameter is going to be a pointer to a location in memory which holds the value of the first character of `buff` regardless of which one (`buff` or `token`) I pass.

I (loosely) understand that `char[]` and `char *` are fundamentally different because arrays are allocated statically and pointers dynamically, but I don't understand why this should make any difference in this case, especially considering the system has no qualms about getting the `strlen` or `strcpy`ing from `token`.

I would love to understand what is happening here.  Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Note, you need to `malloc(len + 1)` for the null terminator.

Comment: Thx, I will edit. Transcription error.

Comment: *I (loosely) understand that char[] and char * are fundamentally different* Kind of sort of but not really. Arrays will "decay" to a pointer to the first element of the array, so you can pass a `char[]` to a function expecting `char*` and it should work. As I understand it, the only real difference between `char[]` and `char*` is, as you point out, static vs dynamic allocation.

Comment: @computerfreaker. An array is a block of contiguous storage, it could be one byte or a trillion bytes. A pointer contains the address of some  storage, typically it is no more than 8 bytes.  This has nothing to do with the allocation type.

Comment: It would help if you show the input data that causes it to crash.

Comment: @poolie It is not contingent on input data.  This will segfault as soon as it attempts to execute line 20 no matter what the input.

Comment: @SamHazleton Hm, OK. It would still be a better question if you showed all the inputs you've separately tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works without any errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char *token, *temp;
    int len;
    char buff[81] = "test me # a comment"; 

    len = strlen(buff);
    token = strtok(buff, "#"); 

    if (len != strlen(token)) {
        printf("comment: %s\n", strtok(NULL, "#"));
    }

    token = strtok(token, " "); 

    printf("first word: %s\n", token);
    return 0;
}
```

It is possible that you have some other problem before the given segment. I don't see any reason to use `malloc` really.

Comment: You are right.  Apparently there was something else causing the problem, so now I am wondering why using `malloc` and `strcpy` avoided the segfault I was hitting.  I think I will go back into my code and see if I can find some answers.

Comment: Yes, it will work on that hardcoded string. But it will also crash on an input line containing only `#`.

Answer (score 4):

[`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) is kind of a strange function in that it mutates the input buffer to insert nuls, and maintains internal state.

You are generally better off avoiding `strtok` and using `strchr` instead. Calling strtok repeatedly on pointers into the same buffer is likely to crash.

Either way, as a general rule, functions don't reject malloc'd memory. It's a clue you have some corruption going on, whether you use malloc or not. Running your program under Valgrind or similar will make it more obvious where.

So, why specifically does it crash here?

If the line contains a `#` then the first call to `strtok` will replace the `#` with a nul. Either way it returns a pointer to the first non-# byte of the string.

Your second call to strtok prints the string between the first and second `#` which is probably not what you want.

One problem you may be having here is that `strtok` returns null on lines that contain no non-delimiter characters. For example an empty line or a line with only spaces will cause `token` to get set to null and then the printf will crash.

---

A better version (untested) would be something like this:

```
char *star, *token, *arg;
star = strchr(buff, '#');
if (star) *star = '\0';
token = strtok(buff, " \t");
if (!token)
    continue; // empty line
printf("operator: %s\n", token);
while ((arg = strtok(NULL, " \t")) != NULL) 
    printf("arg: %s\n", arg);
```

Important things here:

- check for null ;)
- we don't use strtok to do something more easily done with strchr
- for each string, first strtok points to the buffer and gets the first word, then the rest use null

But as I said, I would strongly consider using avoiding it if the syntax is nontrivial.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `strchr`, I will likely employ that in the future.  As far as the problem goes, this program processes the text from an assembly language program.  The call to `strtok(NULL, "#")` will print out the comment on a line if there is one.  in the interest of space, this code is not fully functional to process lines where '#' is the first character.  The crash occurs on the call to `token = strtok(token, " ")`.

Comment: line 20.  I am aware that blank lines will cause a problem. I removed all blank and comment only lines from the input when testing.  This problem occurred in my assembler program, but I did not feel my code was sufficiently readable for this question so I wrote a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid segfaults, check that the value returned by `strtok` is not `NULL` before passing it to functions that expect a non-null pointer , such as `printf` and `strlen`.

Your code would work if every string contains a  with a `#` after it; and cause undefined behaviour otherwise.

You can't use `strtok` on a string literal because `strtok` writes to the buffer, and string literals are not writable. However, `char buff[81];` is fine.

BTW `len != strlen(token)` is always true. If this is not clear to you then re-read the documentation for strtok to see what it does.

Comment: I did check the value returned by `strtok` in my program.  I will edit the code in the question to reflect that.  The segfault occurs either way.  Note, `strcpy(temp, token); token = strtok(temp, " ")` works.  This would fail if `token` were `NULL`.

Comment: Also, `len != strlen(token)` is not always true.  the call to `strtok(buff, "#")` places a `'\0' where there used to be a `'#'` and returns a pointer to the first token in the modified buffer, which in this case is the first character in the buffer.  Therefore, if `len` is evaluated before the `strtok` (which it is) and there was a `'#'` somewhere on the line, `len != strlen(token)`. If there is no `'#'` on the line, then `strtok` will not replace any characters, and `len == strlen(token)`.

Comment: OK about the length. But if `token` is `NULL`, then `strcpy(temp, token);` causes undefined behaviour. It does not necessarily do what you are calling "fail".

Answer (score 0):

So really, the more general answer to "why is my C program crashing" is *not* to post it to StackOverflow and ask, or to change it until the problem's hidden, but rather:

1. Check whether functions can return null and if so whether you handle it correctly - `strtok` can and you don't.
2. Run it under Valgrind or any of dozens of other memory checkers that will flag the error as soon as it occurs, rather than it perhaps corrupting memory and crashing later.
3. Gradually reduce the code and input data until you have the smallest case that shows the problem.
4. Carefully read the manual for the functions you're calling and check how they handle these inputs and what their pre/post conditions are.
5. Read some of the [460 other questions tagged strtok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strtok) because it's almost certainly been asked before.